# How To Return Summation of Last Non Blank Value of Each Product

Tags: powerbi, dax, lookup, measure

I have a table that contains information of date, site, product and balance.

| Date | Site | Product | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-23 | A | A1 | 100 |
| 1-Jan-23 | A | A2 | 120 |
| 2-Jan-23 | B | B1 | 200 |
| 2-Jan-23 | A | A1 | 130 |
| **1 Feb 23** | B | B1 | 50 |

In my page, there are some slicer of Year, Month and Site. One visual will display **Total Last Balance** (affected by Month and Year), eq I select **January** it will display sum of product A1+A2+B1 which is 130+120+200=450, but when I select **February** it will display sum of product A1+A2+B1 (includes some of January) which is 130+120+50=300. I expect this scenario will happen in another visual that display end balance by site or product. Would you please to suggest dax that I ve to write in measure. Thanks in advance